# RemObjects Silver: Doesn't recognize arc4random_uniform

Tags: swift, debugging, random, arc4random, remobjects

So I just started using RemObject's Swift compiler, Silver, but it doesn't seem to recognize the function arc4random_uniform(). I have tried researching this problem but could not fin an answer. Here is my code:

```
let randomNumber: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(100)
println(randomNumber)
```

The console gives me this error message:

```
(E46) Unknown identifier "arc4random_uniform"
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or do I have to import or configure something?

Comment: Leaving aside the ancient `println` (Swift 1.2?), you could try to double-check that you've imported `Foundation` (or `Darwin`). If these are not accessible, you might consider using `random()` accessible by importing `Glibc`.

Comment: Whenever I try to import something it gives me an error message: '(E26) Unknown namespace "Darwin" in uses list'. I tried using just the regular print() before but it didn't work and told me to use println(). Maybe it's outdated?

Comment: I haven't used RemObjects Silver, but it seems your compiler is set to using the ancient Swift 1.2 (or you wouldn't be prompted using the ancient `println(..)`). Regarding `arc4random_uniform`, there is an open bug report, [SR-685](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-685), which describes that there is no `arc4random_uniform()` function in Glibc. See also [this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/317215/having-issues-using-arc4random-uniform.html).

Comment: I looked and copied the answer in the forum, but got the same error messages for import and random(). I can't seem to be able to import anything, is that worth another question?